# Entity Framework 4.3 How to save a column value Mutually exclusive between records?

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

Is there any way i can save a specific column value mutually exclusive between records.

Ex : I have an Address table and i want to save "IsPrimaryAddress " column to true. So when i add the second Address  record for the Same Person with IsPrimaryAddress  value True, I want to update the other records which has the IsPrimaryAddress value to be null so that only one address will have IsPrimaryAddress value =True

Answer (score 1):

That is your domain logic and you must implement it in your application. EF will not help you with domain logic - it is framework for data access. Database can handle this only if you create an insert/update trigger and that is pretty ugly way to implement your domain logic.

Comment: Does that means, I should get all Address records and reset the Column to null before saving the new record ?

Comment: If you want to do that with EF the answer is yes. You can also create stored procedure for that to avoid pulling records from database just to reset one field.